# Python portable, linux & windows

Tags: python, linux, windows, usb-drive

I am using linux at home but at school we use windows 7. I want to have python installed on my usb to that I can use it for both windows  and linux (ubuntu 13.04). Is there a way that I can install python on my usb so that both win and linux computers can use it? I am more interest in python 2.7. I have Wine installed on my linux machine. It might no be ideal but could I use portable python and run it under wine?

Comment: Well, you can test whether Portable Python runs under Wine, but it probably does. Is that all you were asking?

Comment: is there a reason for doing that?

Comment: The schools computer do not have python and I can't install it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can install two python's. Download Anaconda from http://continuum.io/ website for linux and windows. Install them (on win and lin machines) and then create two environments on your USB using the `conda` package manager:

```
# Windows
conda create -p E:\pywin python all other packages you want
# Linux
conda create -p /mnt/usb/pylin python all other packages you want
```

Then use the `pywin` environment on windows and `pylin` on linux.

```
# Windows
D:\pywin\python.exe your_script.py
# Linux
/mnt/usb/pylin/bin/python your_script.py
```

With `conda` you will be able to maintain the same packages in both environments so you'll have everything you need on both systems...

Or you can install the Anaconda directly to the USB, but that will require more space...

Comment: I can't can't install python any of the school computers. Like I said will only be able to run python from the usb. Does this still work in my scenario?

Comment: @Gecko: You will need to borrow a Windows machine from somewhere—or set up a Windows virtual machine on your linux box—in order to create the Windows environment for your USB drive. After that, it will work on machines that don't have Python installed on it.

Comment: @Gecko You can also install anaconda directly to usb. But it will take more space...

Comment: Yes, you can run it like this for simple scripts, but as of 2021, in windows every package is being pushed in user profile like this - PLOTLY_DIR = os.environ.get(
    "PLOTLY_DIR", os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), ".plotly")

Comment: see discussion here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39984611/can-anaconda-be-packaged-for-a-portable-zero-configuration-install#:~:text=TO%20make%20Anaconda3%20truly%20portable,user-data%20in%20a%20dedicated

Answer (score 0):

You could always try a browser based solution with the files hosted in .txt files on Google Drive or Dropbox. [Skulpt.com](http://www.skulpt.org/) syncs with GitHub too, so you can work that way.