# How to install Python 2.7.10 installation without root/sudo permission and internet connection?

Tags: python

I have been trying to install Python 2.7.10 along with more than 15 supporting packages in the following environment.

```
LSB_VERSION=base-4.0-amd64:base-4.0-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-amd64:printing-4.0-noarch
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.4 (Santiago)
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.4 (Santiago)
```

But I don't have root root, sudo permission. I don't even have internet connection on that. I can only copy the package files from Windows to Linux machine. And then I have to install everything.

Can anyone help me complete this task?

Comment: "... only copy the package files from Windows to Linux machine" -- does the Windows machine have internet access?  You can build it from source pretty easily, just download the source release tarball.  Or binaries from portable python, or `pypy`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [miniconda](http://conda.pydata.org/miniconda.html) to install a standalone python. Then create environments as needed using the miniconda tool (conda).

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19170873/3586654) for example usage.

If you already have a python installed (maybe the system python), you can skip downloading miniconda and use [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/) to create standalone environments instead.

You can then use `pip` to install the packages that you need.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance. I have successfully installed the latest python version 2.7.12. But now I have been struggling to install the packages. As I said there is no internet connection on the linux box. If I try to install from source again it is asking dependent packages. Any more light on this?

Comment: You could install miniconda on a machine which has network access. You create the conda environment on this machine and install the packages here. After all packages have been installed, copy the environment directory to the machine without network access.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance. I have successfully installed it.