# How can I prepare an Anaconda environment for transfer to a PC without internet access?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I have some python code on my PC, and an Anaconda environment with all the packages required to run it. This code has to be run on a PC that doesn't have any access to the internet, so the only way to transfer data to it would be with a USB stick. The destination PC already has Anaconda installed, with only the default `base` environment that comes with the installation.

What is the best way to clone the environment on my PC to the PC that can't access the internet?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can Anaconda be packaged for a portable zero-configuration install?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39984611/can-anaconda-be-packaged-for-a-portable-zero-configuration-install)

Comment: you could maybe create a custom os image and apply it to your air gapped machine.

Comment: Have you already checked out [conda pack](https://conda.github.io/conda-pack/)?